# $ax^2+by^2+2gx+2fy+2hxy+c=0$ : Understanding the equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Given any second degree equation in $x$ and $y$,

$ax^2+by^2+2gx+2fy+2hxy+c=0$

is it possible to find out the centre and/or the axis of the conic section it represents?

What information can I gather simply by looking at the curve?

For example one thing my teacher taught me was that if $h=0$ the axis of the curve(be it parabola,hyperbola,ellipse etc) is parallel to the coordinate axes.

I am looking for some other information that the equation can offer.

Comment: You could start with taking a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections).

Comment: :| Everything on that page seems so complex.I am still in high school so I didn't understand all that.I would be grateful if you could simplify those statements on the page.I do have a working knowledge of partial derivatives and matrices/determinants

Comment: I don't have the time to go into detail. If $h=0$, it is easy to transform the general equation into one of the standard equations of the different conic sections, the type of conic and its properties (center, axes etc) follow immediately then. A useful trick to turn the equation into a standard form is [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). If $h \ne 0$, you'll need to perform a rotation to get rid of this mixed term.

Answer (score 3):

For obtaining the center (if there is one: if it is a parabola, there is no center), compute the partial derivatives (ask your teacher if necessary) of $f$ with respect to $x$, then to $y$, and write that they are zero: you will get a system of 2 linear equations with two unknowns, the solution of which is the coordinates of the center.

Let us take the example of

$$f(x,y)=4x^2 + y^2 + 6x y - 4 x=0$$

(plotted below: it's a hyperbola). The partial derivatives are:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=&-4+8x+6y\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=&6x+2y\end{cases}$$

Equating these expressions to zero, we obtain $x=-2/5, y=6/5$ that can be verified to be the coordinates of the center of the hyperbola.

Furthermore, if the asymptotes are desired, we consider points at infinity that are obtained in the following way : we eliminate in (1) all terms which aren't of second degree. It remains

$$F(x,y):=y^2+6xy+4x^2=0\tag{2}$$

No, we look for what happens along lines $y=mx$ that we substitute in (2) giving the equation:

$$x^2(m^2+6m+4)=0$$

This is possible with the two slopes

$$m=-3\pm \sqrt{5}\tag{3}$$

As the asymptotes must pass through the center, their equations will be

$$y-6/5=m(x+2/5)$$

with $m$ given by (3).

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Can I find the axis of the curve?